# Set layout depending on request.xhr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, security, layout, render

I've been struggling with a Rails project recently where essentially every page of the project needs to be accessible both via regular navigation (for older browsers) and via AJAX without a layout. I recently found a solution to the problem by putting this at the top ApplicationController:

```
layout proc { request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
```

This line should cause all the controller actions to render with a layout when accessed normally, and without a controller when accessed via AJAX, but it seems a bit too good to be true.

I was wondering if there may be any security or performance downfalls of this approach that I'm forgetting? Is there a better way of doing it? Is there any possibility that some obscure, old browser may render without the layout when it should be accident, or visa versa?

Basically, am I overlooking anything? Could this be dangerous?

Comment: Isn't this sort of the idea behind turbolinks?

Comment: Turbolinks still appears to be loading with layout, but that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Why is it doing that? Will it do that on all browsers? I'm going to test it.

Comment: I've never personally used turbolinks, so I can't speak to the browser compatibility, but I believe it just falls back to regular links if it's not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to use this in the future, I've discovered that it does cause trouble with the Devise gem if its views are pulled with xhr. For some reason, Devise likes to dump the flash into the response rather than putting it in a flash. It's probably the last line in some method that I'm too lazy to go looking for, as it would mean cracking open the devise black box.

This isn't technically because of this line, but just for future reference, look out. Don't put devise views in AJAX modals or be careful if you do.